# Is it possible to draw a round?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

If the last survivors of both team die at the same time (by a grenade, for example), who wins? Is it possible to get a draw? If yes, does the round still count in the 30 rounds of competitive?

Comment: I can't answer for sure, but I'm sure I remember 3kliksphilip doing a video on something similar, and found that one person always dies first or something. Apart from that, I don't think a draw would make sense, since even if everybody died, that means the CTs still did their job and stopped the Ts from planting and detonating. Like I said I'm not too sure, so I'm just commenting for now. Good question, though.

Comment: A link to said video would complete the answer nicely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@CommandoAir's Answer was correct, it is not possible, one player always dies first, even if the time diffrence is only milliseconds. It was possible in previous CS version due to grenades, but its not possible in CS:GO.

Here is the video from 3kliksphilip:

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible.

One further example is a sniper duel. When you get hit first, even if you hear your shot, it will not take effect, the shot "magically" disappears.

**One person always dies first!**